# How to cluster addresses into paperboy rounds

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, pseudocode

Assume i have a list of newspaper subscribers and their geographical location (f.e. postal codes) and the distance between different locations.

The goal is cluster subscribers together in 'rounds'. The size/length of a round is constrained by time: there is only limited time available for delivery each morning. This limits maximum distance per round.

Is their an algorithm that allows me to cluster subscribers/addresses into 'rounds' in such a manner that I minimise the number of required paperboys/rounds?

Comment: Search for "vehicle routing problem". It's NP-hard, natch.

Comment: Are these the same employees as the 'salesmen' in your previous question ?  What a come down !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sales area partitioning between salesreps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433238/sales-area-partitioning-between-salesreps)